# Graph Plotting Help - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for some advice and guidance on possible exploratory data analysis graphs (and code to plot, am new at python) that I can plot for some internet clicks data that I have.

I have a column with **users** (1500 rows), of which 249 are unique values.
I have another column which contains the **date and time** (in a datetimestamp format) when the user clicked (I am not interested in the date, its only the time that I am interested in).

I have been asked to analyse the relationship between the users and the time.

What sort of graph can I plot to illustrate this relationships.

Another quirk is that the data was imported as a csv fie, so the date and time column is currently of the type "object).

Answer (score -1):

Histogram is a simple way to show relation `user_count ~ time`. For example, if you want to see how many users a clicked in every hour, use hour part of timestamp and set `bins = 24` and `range=(0, 24)`. See: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/hist.html for code examples.